# Idiomatic schadenfreude phrases

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for an idiomatic phrase you would say to somebody you hate when something bad happens to them. For example, they could fall and break their knee or had bad news, etc. You wish them more of it, and you say it in their face.

Comment: An English-language-learner could say "Shit has happened."

Comment: For more bang, this might work then, shit happens! and it couldn't happen to a nicer son-of-a-bitch!
Though I was wondering why the restrictive suggestion to English-language-learners.
Thanks TRomano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your reason for disliking them is justified – let's assume this individual is a really nasty person who frequently belittles and berates others – then one idiomatic phrase you could use is:

> *Karma's a bitch*.

You can read more about this well-used phrase on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-karma-is-a-bitch), and also on our sister site [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120956/why-is-karma-a-bitch).

<sup>If you wanted, you could even give this person the [t-shirt](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1304&bih=931&q="karma%27s+a+bitch"+t-shirt).</sup>

Comment: Similar to "Life sucks, doesn't it?"

Comment: @user3169 - Yes, especially when that one is uttered with a dash of obvious sarcasm.

Comment: Very mean! I think it is the best. Though some ripostes are interesting too!
How about, "Shit happens 'cause Karma's a bitch."? Would it sound okay?

Comment: @learner - It would sound rather crude, but, if you don't mind sounding vulgar in this instance, you could say that. It packs a punch, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6):

If you want that person to experience something bad because they behave badly towards other people, then you might consider

> [taste of your own medicine](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+taste+of+own+medicine)
>   a sample of the unpleasantness that one has been giving other people

Then depending on what exactly you want to express, you can say something like

> I'm glad you got a taste of your own medicine!

This means exactly that you are glad that this person also experienced something bad.

To imply that you want them to continue having bad experiences, you might be able to say "I hope you keep taking it!" But this is something I made up. I think it is understandable, but it is not commonly used.

Comment: Thanks probablyme. Well, I do not know about the usage in English, but it sounds as if it is suited in situations where you get a similar treatment/punishment to the ones you have given/caused to others while I am looking for phrases to use regardless of the person's doings. Having a car accident because you have been rude to your coworkers does not qualify for the use of this expressions now does it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I think it has to be the same or equivalent. In your scenario, I would same something like "Life's a bitch, ain't it?" And it has to be in a tone (cocky tone?) that lets the person know that you enjoy that they had an accident. If you didn't know, "bitch" is offensive language, so you have to be careful when you use it. Also, "ain't" is slang. Also, I do not believe that it implies that you wish them more bad things.

Comment: Thank you. As for the *wish*, it is not a requirement but would be "so much the better". Yes, I'm well aware of the register.

Comment: If the person knows that they are well-known for being rude, then you might also be able to say "It final came back to bite you in the ass!" where _it_ refers to the person being rude all the time. This is similar to "life's a bitch" and "karma's a bitch". There was another one that I thought of, by I forgot it! If I remember, I will tell you.

Comment: @learner: In contexts where things like *How d'ya like a taste of your own medicine?* or *You can dish it out, but you can't take it!* don't fit, you can still throw out a bitter *What goes around comes around*. But again, that can be used in positive contexts as well (you get back all the love you give out), so you're basically relying on sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't a lot of set phrases for this in English. In my experience, this is less about what you say and more about how you say it.

Typically, I would expect this message to be conveyed with a relatively bland phrase and an acid delivery. In that context, any of the following would work:

> It couldn't have happened to a nicer fellow
>
> *What* a shame!
>
> I'm *so* sorry to hear that!

Comment: +1 About set phrases and a nicer fellow. I was in two minds whether to choose yours or J.R.'s

Answer (score 2):

You could say you [gloated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gloat) over your enemy's bad luck.

> **gloat** *- dwell on one's own success or another's misfortune with smugness or malignant pleasure*

But note that most people aren't likely to approve of you gloating, and I don't think this would change if you found a different "synonym" (it's not a "nice" thing to do, regardless of what words are used).

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. I might not have put it clear enough, but I wanted to a phrase that I would say it to somebody to them face to face not about them.
As to the manners and behavior, I ask to learn not necessarily to practice. You could assume the role of a criminal when you write a horror story.

Comment: Well, there are any number of things you could say to your suffering enemy that would leave him in no doubt that you either don't care or you're actually *enjoying* his misfortune. Though I have to be honest, I probably hear *Life's a bitch* more often expressed in ***sympathy***. Obviously if the other guy *knows* you don't like him, he'll presumably assume that anything you say that seems superficially sympathetic is in fact sarcastic. So you might as well say *Oh! I feel really sorry for you!*

Comment: To quote Woody Allen: "So I said unto him, I said 'Be fruitful, and multiply....but not in those words."